# Searching through code for a tag that is missing a variable

Tags: regex, coldfusion

I am sure that what I am trying to do is very simple but I am new to regex.

I am searching through millions of lines of code. What I need to find are `<cffunction>` tags that are missing the `output=` attribute. For instance this should match:

```
<cffunction name="qrySelectQuestions" access="public" returntype="query">
```

However, this should not:

```
<cffunction name="qrySelectQuestions" access="public" output="no" returntype="query">
```

Note, the `output` attribute could be anywhere within the tag definition.

Answer (score 1):

Using this answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/406408/4456875

```
<cffunction ((?!output).)*>
```

Comment: Thank you, Jonathan! I knew it would be simple and this works perfectly!